# Error in executing a query in play 2.0 framework

Tags: java, sql, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I just want to fetch the data with particular id. My method containing query is:

```
public static List getidProducts(Integer id) {
    List<Products> productsid = Products.find("product_id IN:id").bind("id", id).fetch();
    return productsid;
}
```

I am getting the error: **symbol not found** and it indicates the error to be in the method **find()**.
Where am i wrong? Pls suggest me.

**Here is my products.java**

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.format.*;
import play.data.validation.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Products extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer product_id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String productname;

    @Constraints.Required
    public Integer quantity;
    @Constraints.Required
    public Integer price;

    public static Finder<Integer,Products> find = new Finder<Integer,Products>(Integer.class, Products.class); 

    public static List getidProducts(Integer id) {
        return Products.find().where().in("id", id).findList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this still Ebean ? Weird aproach, try this:

```
public static List<Products> getidProducts(Integer id) {
    return Products.find.where().in("product_id", id).findList();
}
```

Nota bene isn't your product_id unique field? In such case, you should return a Products object not List.

```
public static Products getidProducts(Integer id) {
    return Products.find.where().eq("product_id", id).findUnique();
}
```

or simplier:

```
public static Products getidProducts(Integer id) {
    return Products.find.byId(id);
}
```

Comment: Yes product_id is a unique field. And i am still facing the same problem in find(), when i tried your code.
My Products.java is as shown above, please guide me where actually the problem is?

Comment: Oops I made a typo in sample it should be `find.where()` not `find().where()`, check now

Comment: Thanks a lot biesior, the first query worked fine for me. U are a genius.